# Trouble Updating MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

So Basically got a script that checks users numbers (they chosen) against another table of numbers.
The script checks how many they matched and updates it their user row.

The problem i am having is that when it updates all the users it uses the first user numbers and updates how many they matched on everyones.

The script is quite messy so sorry about that.

```
<?
include "../includes/db_connect.php";

$sql="SELECT * from users WHERE status='Alive'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$number = 0;
$number_wrong = 0;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 

    $one2=$rows['1'];
    $two2=$rows['2'];
    $three2=$rows['3'];
    $four2=$rows['4'];
    $five2=$rows['5'];
    $six2=$rows['6'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$one2' OR `2` = '$one2' OR `3` = '$one2' OR `4` = '$one2' OR `5` = '$one2' OR `6` = '$one2' ");
    $get = mysql_num_rows($q);

    if($get == 0) {
       ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
        ++$number;
    }

    $q23 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$two2' OR `2` = '$two2' OR `3` = '$two2' OR `4` = '$two2' OR `5` = '$two2' OR `6` = '$two2' ");
    $get23 = mysql_num_rows($q23);

    if($get23 == 0) {
       ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
    ++$number;
    }

    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$three2' OR `2` = '$three2' OR `3` = '$three2' OR `4` = '$three2' OR `5` = '$three2' OR `6` = '$three2' ");
    $get2 = mysql_num_rows($q2);
    if($get2 == 0) {
        ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
        ++$number;
    }
    $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$four2' OR `2` = '$four2' OR `3` = '$four2' OR `4` = '$four2' OR `5` = '$four2' OR `6` = '$four2' ");
    $get3 = mysql_num_rows($q3);
    if($get3 == 0) {
        ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
        ++$number;
    }
    $q4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$five2' OR `2` = '$five2' OR `3` = '$five2' OR `4` = '$five2' OR `5` = '$five2' OR `6` = '$five2' ");
    $get4 = mysql_num_rows($q4);
    if($get4 == 0) {
        ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
        ++$number;
    }
    $q5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$six2' OR `2` = '$six2' OR `3` = '$six2' OR `4` = '$six2' OR `5` = '$six2' OR `6` = '$six2' ");
    $get5 = mysql_num_rows($q5);
    if($get5 == 0) {
        ++$number_wrong;
    } else {
        ++$number;
    }
}

$sql="SELECT * from users WHERE status='Alive' ORDER by id ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 
    $membernames=$rows['email'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `number` = '$number' WHERE `email` = '$membernames'"; 
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
}
?>
```

Comment: Any Help would be brilliant. If this not possible please let me know

Comment: that is a lot of queries, and not properly indented, so it is difficult to follow your code. can you take some time and indent your code so it is easier to read?

Comment: Sean sadly it is hard using tabs and how s.o.   shows it

Comment: Sean, Did i indent all the code by mistake and should only indent the queries? Sorry i don't really understand how to use this site properly.

Comment: I think the problems are:
This line could be wrong: $sql="SELECT * from users WHERE status='Alive'"; 
or it could be this line that could be wrong:
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `number` = '$number' WHERE `email` = '$membernames'"; 
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");

Comment: Your problem is that you do your 1st query/loop, and overwrite the values for each user. Then you do another query/loop to do the insert, but after/outside the 1st query/loop, so your `$number` value will be the last set value. You need to do your insert inside your 1st query/loop code.

Comment: @DrewPierce not sure I understand what you mean. (also you need a @ before a name or it won't message the user). If pasted code is already properly formatted/indented, then using the `{}`button in the SO editor, it will do the 'hard' work for you.

Comment: @sean 90% of my code works how it should the only problem is when it updates all the users it updates the column "number" with the first user answer. It should update it everyone with how many numbers they matched. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Stop using the deprecated mysql extension

Comment: Indenting and fixed misplaced braces.