# PHP, Stripe API Won't Update MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

My Stripe API php script is working but won't update the mysql database when the payment is sucessful

PHP:

```
if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey("API HERE");
  $error = '';
  $success = '';

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['street']) || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['zip']))
      throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $total1,
                                "currency" => "gbp",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                "description" => $_POST['email']));
    $success = '<? mysql_query("UPDATE `invoices` SET `paid`="Paid" WHERE `number`="1459""); ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
                </div>';
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
              </div>';
  }
}
?>
```

The $total1 all works,
Just this line won't work

```
$success = '<? mysql_query("UPDATE `invoices` SET `paid`="Paid" WHERE `number`="1459""); ?>
```

Where it says API HERE their is a API key i just blanked it out for security purposes.

The mysql table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `invoices`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `issue` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `due` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `paid` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `subtotal` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `discount` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `total` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `stripetotal` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `invoices`
--
```

Comment: If you are using mysql 5.* (or higher), please consider changing the `mysql` API to `mysqli` or `PDO`. It is not recommended to use the old `mysql` API on new projects: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: This was an old API script i was working with, I will update the mysql to mysqi. Thanks

Comment: @KompjoeFriek Do you have any idea how to get this working?

Comment: I think Norbert tried to let you figure that out for your self. You did something similar not too long ago, please take a look at your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955561/trouble-updating-mysql-table. Notice the difference around the `mysql_query` lines?

Comment: I recoded the api completely and it worked now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes in the string:

```
"UPDATE `invoices` SET `paid`="Paid" WHERE `number`="1459""
```

This should read:

```
`number`=\"1459\"
```

or

```
`number`='1459'
```

or

```
`number`=1459
```

The same goes for paid:

```
`paid`='Paid'
```

Comment: So it should be
    "UPDATE `invoices` SET `paid`='Paid' WHERE `number`='1459' " ?

Comment: Yes, unless number is an integer field in the database, then removing the `'` is even better since it prevents any conversions of the data on database side.

Comment: Yes i tried that one before but it comes up with this error,
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Paid' (T_STRING) in /home/phantomv/public_html/taxi/payment.php on line 347

Comment: Add the `create table` of the invoices table to the question please.

Comment: I have added the table of the invoices in to the question. Thanks

Comment: I see: Also remove the **'<?** and **?>** from the line `$success = '<? mysql_query("UPDATE `invoices` SET `paid`="Paid" WHERE `number`="1459""); ?>`. You have to rewrite that line a bit more :)

Comment: I have removed the '<? ?>' from that line, Now it just shows up as text. You said i need rewrite it abit more, Could you help me on that please? Thanks for your help so far.